# How to read system-properties from appengine-web.xml?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, properties

I want to read system-properties for `appengine-web.xml` in my Java code. I have tried using `System.getProperty()` but it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Set values like below in `appengine-web.xml`. Then you can get using `System.getProperty()`

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="myapp.maximum-message-length" value="140" />
</system-properties>
```

**Reference :**

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?hl=en#Java_appengine_web_xml_System_properties_and_environment_variables